# Which MP4 specification defines the ES_Descriptor bit layout?

Tags: mp4

In ISO 14496-14 section 5.6.1 they define an ESDSBox which contains an ES_Descriptor.  Section 3.1.2 references some fields of the ES_Descriptor, but I have yet to figure out where the bit layout of the structure is defined.

Which document and section defines the layout of the ES_Descriptor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in ISO/IEC 14496-1, section 7.2.6.5.

Comment: Thanks, it was missing from the 1998 version of the spec I had.  I had to get the 2010 version.